# data scraping - field value - issue

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I like to obtain actual informaction about the numbers of infected from this website: https://www.gov.pl/web/koronawirus/wykaz-zarazen-koronawirusem-sars-cov-2

my code looks like:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
adresURL = 'https://www.gov.pl/web/koronawirus/wykaz-zarazen-koronawirusem-sars-cov-2'
res = requests.get(adresURL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
data = soup.select('.details-property-value')
print(data)
```

as a result I'm receiving:

```
[<div class="details-property-value" tabindex="0">{{selectedRecord[commonColumns[index]] || '-'}}</div>]
```

Any ideas how to get value of fields ? Am i missing sth ?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by ```fields```? I'm not sure personally I get what you are trying to achieve here or which part of the html you want to extract data from

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you're trying to scrape the table on that page. It looks like there is some JSON baked into the HTML:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

url = "https://www.gov.pl/web/koronawirus/wykaz-zarazen-koronawirusem-sars-cov-2"

response = requests.get(url)
response.raise_for_status()

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

data = json.loads(soup.find("pre", {"id": "registerData"}).text)
print(data)
```

Comment: Yes, I meant to get the data from the table. Could you give me a hint why you use the "registerData" clausule?

Comment: @Markoyee I simply picked that `pre` tag (with id `registerData`) because it was the tag that immediately contained the JSON to be scraped. If you view the page source in your browser you'll see what I'm talking about.